# Limited exponential growth interpolation algorithm

Tags: interpolation, equation

I need to implement limited exponential growth interpolation. I found for the formula for this on Wikipedia:

```
B(t)=S-(S-B(0))*e^(-k*t)
```

I have to points marking the beginning and the endpoint of the curve I want to create:
[image]

I only need the values of the curve in whole number intervals e.g. 0,1,2,3, END
So from my point of view, I need to solve the above equation for the k to since I have everything else given.

The problem with this is that the equation

```
B(END_X)=END_Y-(END_Y-START_Y)*e^(-k*END_X)
```

Has no solution since it only approximates the desired END_Y value and never reaches it.

My question is how would I implement calculating the k most efficiently without jumping through a lot of hoops e.g. increasing the END_Y a tad bit above the actually desired endpoint? (Language is C++)

EDIT://

```
END_Y-(END_Y-START_Y)*e^(-k*END_X)=END_Y+sgn(END_Y-START_Y)*G
```

Where G is a proximity parameter.

Comment: What kind of curve do you want to create? If you want to calculate the `k` of an exponential curve that reaches `END_Y` for `t=END_X`, `END_Y` cannot also be the asymptotic value, as that would only be reached for `t=`infinity (as you already wrote). So you need an additional boundary condition, e.g. a value for `S!=END_Y`.

Comment: Thing is I was told that linear interpolation was feeling too harsh and they wanted something more curve like instead. Since pretty much the two points are my only condition I went for the limited growth thing. 
So i guess the only solution is fiddeling with the S as I expected. Is float arithmetic sufficient for that if my result only needs to be correct at one decimal place?

Comment: You could use something like cubic splines, which are often used for smooth curves. But for only two points, a straight line is already the smoothest solution, isn't it? You would need at least three points for the calculation of a smooth(er) curve, or a boundary condition like the direction or derivative at the start.

Comment: Yes maybe smooth was a bit wrong. They said explicitly they want the curve.

Comment: What is often used is a linear interpolation in the log domain (dB) for functions with exponential behavior. It may correspond to your case

Comment: Could provide me with a starting point, which formular to use?

Comment: @KarstenKoop I edited my starting point for this approach, is this correct? I used a sign function because this has to work for the opposite case END_Y>START_Y as well.

Answer (score 3):

An exponential growth corresponds to functions varying exponentially. In these situations, it is usual to perform a linear interpolation in the log domain, or something equivalent in the linear domain.

Let us call *(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>)* and *(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>)* the first and final points. The interpolation consists in calculating an approximation *y<sub>i</sub>* for each input *x<sub>i</sub>*:

[image]

Linear interpolation in the log domain:

[image]

Which results in the linear domain:

[image]

The last exponent corresponds to a simple variable *t* varying from 0 to 1 in a linear way. This implies that this calculation can be performed iteratively, only one call to `pow()` is needed

Comment: While I find your usage of LaTeX enormously nice, it must be mentioned that this might be problematic in a couple of years if the interface of https://www.codecogs.com/ changes. Your answer will have zero information left. Maybe change it into real text. It will not look as nice, but your answer might survive the test of time.

Comment: @kvantour I agree there is a problem. I like making a distinction between algorithms (or mathematics) with coding. The brother site mathematics accept LaTex formulas. Is there a chance that OS will finally handle it?

Comment: Have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309307/latex-on-stack-overflow-any-way-to-include-a-formula

Comment: @kvantour Thank you. I run though them. Totally depressed now

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. [Here](http://d20u174ifpwkls.cloudfront.net/pymoor/files/2013/03/51090291634-538x386.jpg) is a happy duck to make you feel less depressed.

Comment: @kvantour Thank you!!!. The cousin of this one I guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 1):

For exponential **decay** interpolation

```
 y = A*exp(-k*x)  (1)
```

what is shown in your picture, you need to know at least two points *(x0, y0), (x1, y1)*. In this case you have

```
y0 = A*exp(-k*x0)
y1 = A*exp(-k*x1)

y0/y1 = exp(-k*x0)/exp(-k*x1) = exp(-k(x0-x1))

k = log(y0/y1)/(x1-x0).
```

Find *k* first and then find *A*

```
 A = y0 / exp(-k*x0)
```

After obtaining *k* and *A* you can find *y(x)* at the internal point

```
(x0<x<x1)
```

By formula (1)